# Angular stretch mat-card

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I need to create a responsive mat-card. what i mean is that the mat card stretches based on the content it has. for example if I have two buttons the mat card has a different length if it has a list.
would you have any suggestions?

thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You looking something like this
[image: CardStrech]

I use css

```
.container {
    margin: 36px auto;
    width: 640px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
}

mat-card {
    background-color: tomato;
    width: 320px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

mat-card button {
    background-color: rgb(247, 248, 248);
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

html example:

```
<div class="container">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Card 1</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
            <button mat-raised-button>Button 1</button><br>
            <button mat-raised-button>Button 2</button><br>
            <button mat-raised-button>Button 3</button>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Card 2</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
            <mat-accordion>
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Expansion 1</mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    Content 1
                </mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Expansion 2</mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    Content 2
                </mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Expansion 3</mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    Content 3
                </mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>Expansion 4</mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    Content 4
                </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-accordion>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much but doesn't work, my matcar are not streched

Comment: they failed to fix giving it a minimum height but thank you